VirtualBox segfaults/freezes under custom F40 kernel 6.12.rc4
from my kernels .config:
CONFIG_HAVE_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK=y   
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK=y   
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_MEM_POOL_SIZE=16000   
# CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_DEFAULT_OFF is not set   
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_AUTO_SCAN=y  

Note: No cmdline editing done
from dmesg:
[90508.434647] VirtualBox[40228]: segfault at 28 ip 00007f720d65e9f8 sp 00007fff302f4560 error 4 in UICommon.so   
[45e9f8,7f720d47b000+4a1000] likely on CPU 5 (core 5, socket 0)   
[90508.434656] Code: be f8 e2 ff 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 41 57 41 56 49 be ff ef ff ff ff ff ff 00 41 55 41 54 55 53 48 83 ec 18 <48> 8b 47 28 48 2d 00 10 00 00 49 39 c6 0f 82 b5 00 00 00 48 8d 86   '''

=======================================
'''
[85368.939193] kmemleak: 4 new suspected memory leaks (see /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak)   
[85791.129549] VirtualBox[35771]: segfault at 28 ip 00007ff8b805e9f8 sp 00007fff4d67a120 error 4 in UICommon.so[45e9f8,7ff8b7e7b000+4a1000] likely on CPU 4 (core 4, socket 0)   
[85791.129557] Code: be f8 e2 ff 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 41 57 41 56 49 be ff ef ff ff ff ff ff 00 41 55 41 54 55 53 48 83 ec 18 <48> 8b 47 28 48 2d 00 10 00 00 49 39 c6 0f 82 b5 00 00 00 48 8d 86   
[85925.062442] VirtualBox[35822]: segfault at 28 ip 00007f5bbd45e9f8 sp 00007ffc02983fd0 error 4 in UICommon.so[45e9f8,7f5bbd27b000+4a1000] likely on CPU 1 (core 1, socket 0)   
[85925.062451] Code: be f8 e2 ff 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 41 57 41 56 49 be ff ef ff ff ff ff ff 00 41 55 41 54 55 53 48 83 ec 18 <48> 8b 47 28 48 2d 00 10 00 00 49 39 c6 0f 82 b5 00 00 00 48 8d 86   
'''

=============================================
from strace of virtualbox (cmdline):

(complains about XDG_RUNTIME_DIR-- which is set to /run/user/$(id -u)
mprotect(0x7f4abd2db000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0  
write(14, "8", 1)                       = 1   
futex(0xb5dc3a0, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1730301582,      tv_nsec=734588000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY) = 0   
futex(0xb6279d8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0   
write(14, "8", 1)                       = 1   
futex(0xb5dc3a4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1730301582, tv_nsec=735202000}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY) = 0   
futex(0xb6279d8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0   
futex(0xb58ab30, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, NULL, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)   
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---   
+++ killed by SIGINT +++   

the next numbered strace file only ends with /usr/bin/VBox being invoked I believe.
strace output file #3 interacts with modules and particularly the contents of /sys/modules tree.
What am I looking at ? how can i attack these segfaults? I know C programming but
I would appreciate somebody with more direct knowledge....
